# HTML shows some images inverted and some images are not

Tags: html, css, image

I am making a website where you can upload a picture and display it in another web page. In the html page, some images appear 90 degrees inverted and some images are fine. The source of the images is from an iPhone and I am using Safari browser.

Here is my code:

```
    <div>
        <img src="uploads/<?php echo $row["image"] ?>" alt="Profile Pic" width="300" height="300" style="border-radius: 80px">
    </div>
```

Comment: please add your code

Comment: Please share your code and errors

Comment: Your forgot to read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

@amr As you specified about the image orientation issue. I think you cannot do that thing using HTML you should take developers help for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an image metadata issue. You should read [here](http://www.mandolincafe.com/forum/entry.php?713-Why-is-my-picture-turned-sideways).

Basically it is mensioned that:

> To boil this down in simple terms: if you take a photo with a device
>   that doesn't use EXIF, when it gets uploaded to the web and appears in
>   a web document it may not display as intended.

So maybe you should check if those images got the EXIF data?

In addition, images also got the [Color Space and Color Profiles](http://www.dpbestflow.org/color/color-space-and-color-profiles). You may have problems about some inverted colors of some images, you should apply proper color profiles or spaces when needed.